# how to access the local variable of the class from outside? python

Tags: python

i have enums python file which has :

```
class ClassificationType(object):
    CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0
    MULTICLASS = 1
    MULTILABEL = 2
```

i am writing another python file to get the value of the variable declared inside the enums class.

```
def dataset(model_typ):
    dataset_spec = {
        "classification": enums.ClassificationType.MULTICLASS
    }
```

as per above code, i am able to get the value of MULTICLASS as 1. 
now i need to pass the MULTICLASS/MULTILABEL/CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED as argument(model_type) and pass it to dataset_spec.
how to do it?

thanks in advance

NOTE: i dont want to change enums.py file.

Comment: Is the argument `model_typ` supposed to be a string? Then you could simply do `"classification": getattr(enums.ClassificationType, model_typ)`

Comment: i am expecting the same. it works as above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassificationType(object):
    CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0
    MULTICLASS = 1
    MULTILABEL = 2


def dataset(model_typ_multiclass):
    dataset_spec = {
        "classification": model_typ_multiclass
    }

obj = ClassificationType()
model_typ_multiclass = obj.MULTICLASS
dataset(model_typ_multiclass)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation in your answer

Comment: Not that `dataset` should be in another file

Comment: now it is available only for MULTICLASS. but i want either MULTICLASS/MULTILABEL/CLASSIFICATION_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED should be passed as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code in the other file (not the enums.py file):

```
from enums import ClassificationType as ct
import random
def dataset(model_typ):
    dataset_spec = {
        "classification": model_typ
    }
    print(dataset_spec)
dataset(random.choice([ct.MULTILABEL,ct.MULTICLASS]))
```

Output:

```
{'classification': 2}
```

I just simply changed the value of the `dataset_spec`'s `classification` key to the argument `model_typ` then at the end of the code call the `dataset` function and in the parameters write in the `enums.ClassificationType.MULTICLASS` to get the `enums.py` files `MULTICLASS` variable

Comment: i want the variable name present in the class should be uniquely accessed from outside. for ex: i might access MULTICLASS or MULTILABEL